# Kubernetes cluster down error

Tags: kubernetes

When running following command for cluster down in Kubernetes, I am getting following error:

KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-down.sh

rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/kubelet/pods/16981b98-a3bb-11e5-99fb-00505622b20d/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-0i2n6’: Device or resource busy

I tried to remove it forcefully but then also its not getting removed.

Comment: Ask this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). You are more likely to get an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't taking account pods that are Terminating, nor pods in namespaces other than the default namespace.  Filed an issue:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/20469

Comment: Yes, please look at the issue referenced above.